# My query should return the sum of users per month and not count of users per month

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

```
 return User::thisYear()
            ->selectRaw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%m") as month, COUNT(*) as people')
            ->groupBy('month')
            ->pluck('people', 'month');
```

My query should return the sum of users per month and not count of users per month
So if i have 1 user first month and 2 users second month then the second month should show 3 users total.

Comment: SUM(people.id) as people?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly, but if I do I think there's no logic to count them per month? I mean "1 user first month, 2 users second moth -> display 3". What if we add a 3rd month with say 3 users.. should it then display 6? If yes, simply count the users..?

Comment: so i want it to give me the total users each month